# App stops when Alertdialog postiveButton is clicked to get the radioButton Text which pops up in a Alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

when i click on the layout an Alertdialog pops up with two radioButtons on it. What i want is to get the radioButton text and show that text into Toast when i click the OK button. But after clicking the OK button app stops working. Why?

```
Methodlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Add_AlarmActivity.this);
                    View v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.method_pop,null);

                    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            int selectedId=radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                            radioButton=(RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                            String s=radioButton.getText().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    builder.setView(v);
                    AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            });
```

here is the xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/method_radio"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">
                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Solve math"
                        android:id="@+id/solve_math"
                        android:checked="false"/>
                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Shake"
                        android:id="@+id/shake"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>

                </RadioGroup>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

[here is the log][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vgG6.png

01-24 17:40:27.466 24560-24560/com.example.application.alarta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.application.alarta, PID: 24560
                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.application.alarta.Add_AlarmActivity$3$1.onClick(Add_AlarmActivity.java:175)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: post your dialog xml layout

Comment: Also post the logs if your app is crashing

Comment: Add the crash log

Comment: @NaveenDew i have added the xml file

Comment: @DeepLathia i have added the crash log

Comment: for your radioGroup and radioButton use v.findViewById instead of findViewById inside builder.

Comment: it says make v final

Comment: i got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you are not initializing the `RadioGroup`.

It should be initialized after `View v` is inflated.

```
Methodlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Add_AlarmActivity.this);
        View v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.method_pop,null);

        final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.method_radio);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                int selectedId=radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                RadioButton radioButton=(RadioButton) v.findViewById(selectedId);
                String s=radioButton.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.setView(v);
        AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
});
```

I haven't run the code so there might be changes needed.

Comment: will u please edit the code i have supplied?it would be more helpful.thanks

Comment: @MdAhmedAkash Updated.